# Cannot access offset of type string on string Codeigniter 4

Tags: php, codeigniter-4

I get this error:

> Cannot access offset of type string on string

when trying to loop tag data using `foreach()`

on this line:

```
<li><a href="javascript:void(0);"><?= $tags['tag_berita'] ?></a></li>
```

error log:

```
CRITICAL - 2023-11-08 15:42:50 --> Cannot access offset of type string on string
in APPPATH\Views\front\detail_berita.php on line 253.
 1 SYSTEMPATH\View\View.php(226): include()
 2 SYSTEMPATH\View\View.php(229): CodeIgniter\View\View->CodeIgniter\View\{closure}()
 3 SYSTEMPATH\Common.php(1178): CodeIgniter\View\View->render('front/detail_berita', [], true)
 4 APPPATH\Controllers\Berita.php(73): view('front/detail_berita', [...])
 5 SYSTEMPATH\CodeIgniter.php(915): App\Controllers\Berita->detailBerita('wali-kota-bersama-kajari-pekalongan-teken-mou-bidang-perdata-dan-tun')
 6 SYSTEMPATH\CodeIgniter.php(492): CodeIgniter\CodeIgniter->runController(Object(App\Controllers\Berita))
 7 SYSTEMPATH\CodeIgniter.php(353): CodeIgniter\CodeIgniter->handleRequest(null, Object(Config\Cache), false)
 8 FCPATH\index.php(79): CodeIgniter\CodeIgniter->run()
 9 SYSTEMPATH\Commands\Server\rewrite.php(47): require_once('C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\admin\\public\\index.php')
```

detail_berita.php:

```
<div class="sidebar-item mb-4">
    <h4 class="">All Categories</h4>
    <ul class="sidebar-category">
        <li class="border-danger-subtle"><a class="stretched-link" href="javascript:void(0);">All</a></li>
        <?php foreach ($ktg as $ktgs) : ?>
            <li class="border-danger-subtle"><a class="stretched-link" href="javascript:void(0);"><?= $ktgs['kategori'] ?></a></li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
</div>

<div class="sidebar-item mb-4">
    <h4 class="">Tags</h4>
    <ul class="sidebar-tags">
    <?php foreach ($tag as $tags) : ?>
        <li><a href="javascript:void(0);"><?= $tags['tag_berita'] ?></a></li>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
</div>
```

controller:

```
public function detailBerita($slug_berita)
    {
        $data = [
            'judul' => 'Detail Berita'
        ];

        $data['beritaid'] = $this->b->select('*')
            ->select('tb_berita.updated_at as tgl_berita')
            ->join('tb_kategori', 'id_kategori = kategori_id', 'left')
            ->join('users', 'tb_berita.username = users.username', 'left')
            ->join('tb_user', 'tb_user.user_id = users.id', 'left')
            ->where('slug_berita', $slug_berita, 'after')
            ->find();

        $data['tag'] = $this->b->select('tag_berita')->findAll();

        $data['ktg'] = $this->k->select('*')->orderBy('kategori asc')->findAll();

        // dd($data);

        return view('front/detail_berita', $data);
    }
```

I want to loop the tag data like I did with categories, the categories can appear normally but when I add tag data it gets an error

Comment: I don't use CodeIgniter but the error message should say the line that's failing, you probably cropped it by mistake when pasting here.

Comment: @ÁlvaroGonzález I added the error line

Comment: So you think that `$tags` is an array but in fact it's a piece of text.

Comment: More information about the specific cause of your error is available in your server's error log. There is no way to accurately answer this question without seeing the logs. Try sharing the *latest* error logs in `writable/logs/log-2023-11-07.log`

Comment: added the error log, shouldn't tags be the same as ktgs? how could it be a text?

Comment: Inspect these two variables `$ktgs` and `$tags` and confirm that they are indeed arrays for all cases.